# OpenCV is there a way to resize the showed image to the screen automatically?

Tags: opencv

I am using opencv to show an image. The problem is that the image is large so it is bigger than my huge display.
Is there a way to show this image ***AUTOMATICALLY*** resized to fit in my screen?

Please note that many of the answers to similar questions here fall under two categories:

1. They suggest the use of an option in the namedWindow function, but this *does not* solve the question (I tried and also read carefully the documentation, it never claim it does solve this question)
2. Use resize to manually resize the image. Not automatically. But then how can I know the values to resize?

EDIT: I have been asked to report my claim that WINDOW_NORMAL does not solve the problem. I have right in front of me a script in which first I just do

```
cv.imshow("window",image)
cv.waitKey()
```

and then the same script with

```
cv.namedWindow("window", cv.WINDOW_NORMAL)
#image = cv.resize(image, (960, 540))
#image = cv.resize(image, (1280, 800))
cv.imshow("window",image)
cv.waitKey()
```

The results are the same. The window is as Huge as always.
Now let's see the [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#namedWindow)

> Parameters:
>
> ```
> name – Name of the window in the window caption that may be used as a window identifier.
> flags –
>
> Flags of the window. The supported flags are:
>     WINDOW_NORMAL If this is set, the user can resize the window (no constraint).
>     WINDOW_AUTOSIZE If this is set, the window size is automatically adjusted to fit the displayed image (see imshow() ), and you cannot change the window size manually.
>     WINDOW_OPENGL If this is set, the window will be created with OpenGL support.
> ```

As you can see it clearly says **the user can resize the window (no constraint)**  and in no part it says **AUTOMATICALLY**
so it does not address the problem of this question

Comment: you simply need to `namedWindow("foo", cv.WINDOW_NORMAL)` which makes it resizable, *before* calling `imshow`. explain why you claim that *doesn't* solve it. show what happens, and why that is not what you want. -- if you wanted a full-screen window (you didn't exactly say *that*), there's another flag for that. combined with WINDOW_NORMAL, it'll stretch the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to what Dimitar Veljanovski posted (Thanks!) I did this like this. It is not automatic and it does not occupy the whole screen but I have not received an answer to this

```
h, w, c = image.shape
cv.namedWindow("window",cv.WINDOW_NORMAL)
image=cv.resize(image, (w//3,h//3))

cv.imshow("window",image)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use the following library to obtain the X and Y values of your display:

```
import pyautogui #pip install pyautogui

x = pyautogui.size()[0] # getting the width of the screen
y = pyautogui.size()[1] # getting the length of the screen

print(x,y)
```

Comment: you should read the question again. you gave an answer to something that wasn't asked.